# If $f(x) = 4x - 5$ and $g(x) = 3 x$ , then what is $f(g(2))$?

Tags: functions

If $f(x) = 4x - 5$ and $g(x) = 3 x$ , then $f(g(2)) =?$

EDIT: It seems the question is supposed to be $g(x)=3^x$.

Comment: Can you work out what $g(2)$ is? Once you've done that, can you work out what $f(g(2))$ is?

Comment: Now that you have the right problem, Shekhar, can you follow my comment to get the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- Calulate $g(2)=a$
- Calculate $f(a)=...$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You think if a function as a black box, where inputs come in and transformation takes place. For example, if $g(x) = 3^x$, the function $g$ computes $3$ to the power of every input. So $g(4) = 3^4 = 81,g(z^2) = 3^{z^2}$ for whatever value of $z$, and $$g(2y) = 3^{2y} = \left(3^2\right)^y = 9^y$$ for whatever value of $y$. Similarly, if $h(x)$ is any function, then $g(h(x)) = 3 \cdot h(x)$.

Based on this, can you compute $x = g(2)$ and then $f(g(2)) = f(x)$?

Comment: Can the down-voter please explain the down-vote?

Comment: i will do same on my question but its wrong

Comment: the answer is 31 can you explain  more

Comment: My Answer does not match the answer is 31 can you explain more

Comment: @ShekharMishra do you possibly mean $f(g(3))$ instead of $f(g(2))$?

Comment: I would like to see how you get $31$, @Shekhar.

Comment: If f(x) = 4x – 5 and g(x) = 3^x , then f(g(2)) =
(A) 3
(B) 9
(C) 27
(D) 31
(E) none of the above

Comment: That is a question give me some tips

Comment: @ShekharMishra you misrepresented the question, `3^x` is not $3x$, it is $3^x$. See the updated version of the answer and do some work on your own based on the hints. Now you get $31$.